# Can we take two string from one String in if statement?

Tags: java, string, substring, lexicographic

I want to print Two String Lexicographical largest and smallest. Largest is printed but smallest give output same as largest. Whats problem in my code?

public class Solution {

```
public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
   String sequence = s.substring(0,k);
    String smallest = sequence;
    String largest = sequence;

    for(int i=0;i<=(s.length()-k); i++){

        sequence= s.substring(i,(i+k));

        if    (sequence.compareTo(smallest)<0){
            sequence=smallest;
        }
        if (sequence.compareTo(largest)>0){
            sequence=largest;
        }

            }
    // Complete the function
    // 'smallest' must be the lexicographically smallest substring of length 'k'
    // 'largest' must be the lexicographically largest substring of length 'k'

    return smallest + "\n" + largest;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.next();
    int k = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();

    System.out.println(getSmallestAndLargest(s, k));
}
```

}

Comment: smallest and largest needs to be towards LHS while assigning values to it. So, it has to be largest = sequence and smallest = sequence.

Comment: @sara But why we need to write on LHS?

Comment: variable = value; not the other way round; this is the Java Language Syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(sequence.compareTo(smallest)<0){
    smallest = sequence;
}
if (sequence.compareTo(largest)>0){
    largest = sequence;
}
```

You are comparing `sequence` with the `smallest` and `largest`. And your `sequence` changes in every iteration of the `for loop`. And inside the `if condition`, you are checking if your current `sequence` is smaller/larger than your `smallest` and `largest` and if so, you have to update your `smallest` and `largest` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (sequence.compareTo(smallest)<0){
        smallest=sequence;
    }
    if (sequence.compareTo(largest)>0){
        largest=sequence;
    }
```

In Java language, variable assignment is done as follows.

```
variable = value;
```